# Only updated necessary components in MutableStateFlow<MutableList>

Tags: android, kotlin

Say I have a list in a MutableStateFlow: `MutableStateFlow<MutableList<Int>>`, where I have a fragment displays information of every element of the list. For example, [2, 3, 3] would have a fragment displaying '2', a fragment displaying '3', and another fragment displaying '3'.

Once a state change has occurred in the list, I want to update my UI.

But I only want to update the fragments that has its value changed. For example, if our list changes to [2, 3, 4] I only want to change the last fragment.

Is there a way of doing this?

Note: I know that MutableLists have a complicated way of being handled through MutableStateFlows, as per these posts: [How to update mutable state flow with complex list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75428680/how-to-update-mutable-state-flow-with-complex-list-of-objects), [MutableStateFlow not working with MutableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905480/mutablestateflow-not-working-with-mutablelist). I will be handling updates to my MutableList through deep copying, referenced in this answer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz2IZ.png)

Comment: If you are deep copying, then why not use List in the first place?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It not just complicated. You shouldn't do it at all. Use read-only Lists with StateFlows to ensure you don't accidentally break it. There's no reason a consumer of a Flow should have to mutate the incoming List, so don't make the type mutable. And since you have to make list copies anyway, there's no possible benefit to having a mutable type.

Here's why you have to make list copies. Here's simplified psuedo-code of what's going on under the hood of MutableStateFlow when you change its value:

```
var value: T = initialValue
    get() = field
    set(value) {
        if (value == field) return // do nothing
        field = value
        emitValueToCurrentSubscribedCollectors()
    }
```

Now suppose you have a `MutableStateFlow<MutableList<Int>>` and you do this:

```
val data = MutableStateFlow<MutableList<Int>>(mutableListOf(1, 2, 3))

// ...

// Broken way of updating it:
data.value = data.value.apply {
    this[2] = 5
}

// or:
data.value[2] = 5
data.value = data.value
```

You are setting `value` with the same list instance as before, so when the setter gets to that `if (value == field) return` line, it will always be true because you are comparing the list to itself. The old value in `field` is the same mutated instance and there is no record of the previous contents to compare to.

So you have to fix the code by making a list copy:

```
data.value = data.value.toMutableList().apply {
    this[2] = 5
}

// or:
val newList = data.value.toMutableList()
newList[2] = 5
data.value = newList

//but this is still broken:
data.value[2] = 5
data.value = data.value.toMutableList() // won't work because data was changed before copying
```

But it would be better to make the type of the flow a read-only List so the broken ways of doing it won't even compile. This is more robust.

---

You can map your state flow into three separate flows for each of the fragments so are only updating them when their own data changes. Use `distinctUntilChanged()` to prevent unnecessary updates.

```
private val data = MutableStateFlow<List<Int>>(someInitialList)

fun getDataForFragment(index: Int): Flow<Int> =
    data.map { it[index] }.distinctUntilChanged()
```

These other flows don't need to be StateFlows because the operation to map it is trivial.

Comment: But how would I be able to update my state if I make it a `List`? Maybe there are flaws in my understanding of this. Like, if we have a List and the state supposedly changes, then our list would have to change too, right?

Comment: `flow.value = list.toMutableList().apply { /* your changes here */ }` so you are copying the list. You can use `toMutableList()` on a List or a MutableList. Either way, it is making a copy. If your flow type is read-only List, then it prevents a lot of possible errors and bugs you could create.

Comment: Wait, what is `flow` in this case? Sorry I'm a bit confused

Comment: Your MutableStateFlow. See my updated answer for more in-depth explanation.

Comment: TYSM that makes a lot of sense! Would the logic change if my fragment wanted to update the flow as well?

Comment: Not really, but IMO you should not expose the base MutableStateFlow publicly. Just expose a function for updating it and handle changing it inside that function. This helps encapsulate it better. It's a bit more robust against possible bugs.

Comment: tysm!! I implemented the changes you suggested and posted a followup question of problems I ran into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77182440/fragment-doesnt-update-upon-state-change I was wondering if you can take a quick look at it if you have time :D